# Changing a javascript element style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to grab a javascript element in my development site and change it's style.     I am having no luck - this is the link to the site http://www.best-foods-for-fat-burning.com/wordpress/cat/עוף.
`<span class="price">` there's an element with a NodeName = "#text" which I want to change its style. How can I attempt to change it ? I tried the following to "grab" the element but with no success:

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("#text");
 alert(x.length); 
var y=document.getElementById("#text"); 
alert(y.length); 
var z=document.getElementsByTagName("#text");
```

Any suggestions of how I should grab the element and change its style?

Comment: `var y=document.getElementById("text");`, then `y.style.width="100px"`

Comment: " there's an element with a NodeName = "#text" which I want to change its style" -- show us the element... do you want to select it by id, by class, by tag name?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't immediately obvious from your question, but eventually I twigged that `NodeName="#text"` means that you are dealing with a [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeName). This is *not* an element.

**You cannot style text nodes directly**. You can only style element nodes and have their styles affect the text inside them.

---

You mention `<span class="price">`, so presumably the text node is a child node of the span.

You can style (the first matching) span with that class using:

```
document.querySelector('span.price').style.someProperty = "someValue";
```

Or you could use `querySelectorAll` and loop over the resulting node list to style all the elements that match.

---

Since you mention styling the text node specifically if your question, then you might have a situation like:

```
<span> foo <i> bar </i> baz </span>
```

… where you want to style "foo" and "baz" differently to "bar". To achieve that, you would usually style the span, and then override the styling for `span i`.

Alternatively, you might want to style `foo` without touching `bar` *or* `baz`. In this case, you need additional elements.

```
    <span> <span>foo</span> <i> bar </i> baz </span>
```

Now you can style `span span`.

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('text');//no need to use hash for the id
```

Or if you prefer to use jquery, then use like this:

```
var x = $('#text');//need to use hash for the id
```

Now, you can use `x.length`

Comment: The question does not say that the element has the ID 'text' and the document linked to does not appear to have an element with that id.

Comment: True there is no Id with the name text but a Nodname = "#text"